# How to copy a selection to the OS X clipboard

Tags: macos, vim, clipboard

I have an area selected in Vim. How can I copy it into the OS X clipboard?

(The OS X clipboard can be written to via a pipe to `/usr/bin/pbcopy`)

Comment: just visual select, then `"+y`.

Comment: The vim that ships with OSX *doesn't* have `+clipboard` or `+xterm-clipboard`. You can verify this with `vim --version | grep clipboard`. It's possible to resolve this with `brew install vim --with-client-server`.

Comment: Or use MacVim, which offers a command-line version which can by symlinked in your `~/bin` and then `~/bin` can be inserted into your path ahead of the normal system-installed vim and synonyms.

Comment: Building on what @zx1986 wrote, I did three things:
1) Added the following to my ~/.bashrc in order to alias vi/vim to MacVim's terminal mode:
    `alias vi='mvim -v'`
2) Added the following to ~/.vimrc, which maps Ctrl+c (not Cmd+c):
    `vnoremap <C-c> "+y`
3) Configured Keyboard Maestro to type the key sequence `^c` (Ctrl+C) when running in the terminal (in my case iTerm2)

This makes it possible to use Cmd+c to copy text to the OSX clipboard so that it can be pasted in other OSX applications.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Depending on which version of Vim I use, I'm able to use the `+` register to access the clipboard.

"[Mac OS X clipboard sharing](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing)" may have some ideas that work for you as well.

Comment: For folks with VIM compiled without +clipboard the link above is an excellent resource to give workarounds w/o recompiling VIM

Comment: VERY IMPORTANT DETAIL!!! If you have Vim-version 7.3 then this might not work for you, but if you have Vim-version 7.4 then it does (and sometimes you don't even have to do the whole "+y   ). And you check this by just writing >vim in the terminal and then the version-number is when you start it up.

Comment: this answer is the same as this http://stackoverflow.com/a/680271/2652524

Comment: The `"+` register exists only for X11 (unless you build vim with +X11 support, which will install a X11 server XQuartz in OS X), while OS X doesn't use X11 as its windows system.

Comment: What to do, if both - `vim` and `macvim` have +clipboard. And `clipboard=unnamed` added to `~/.vimrc`? Looks like real pain, tried all workarounds and currently have to use spacemacs, when I know, that I'll have to use global clipboard :)

Comment: Yep, from that wikia post, this works for standard vim on OSX:

`vnoremap <silent><leader>y :<CR>:let @a=@" \| execute "normal! vgvy" \| let res=system("pbcopy", @") \| let @"=@a<CR>`

Answer (score 264):

For [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) and Windows Gvim, simply add the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Now all operations such as `yy`, `D`, and `P` work with the clipboard. No need to prefix them with `"*` or `"+`.

Comment: I've spent all morning figuring out how to separate y, d and P commands from ⌘-C and ⌘-V that MacVim enables for you and finally came across this. Sure enough, I had added this to my vimrc when I was a vim juvenile and it has frustrated me ever since.

Comment: For those new to MacVim, it is usable from the terminal with the `-v` flag (`mvim -v`). I have mine aliased to vim and mvim.

Comment: As mentioned by @VincentG in his comment above, this indeed works with terminal-based versions of Vim, but those using tmux within the terminal will need to follow one of the solutions detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11421329/456584

Comment: this should be the accepted answer -- as long as `:echo has("clipboard")` says `1`, which is the case for MacVim, and I have a `vi` alias that runs `mvim -v` instead

Comment: For what it's worth, this doesn't work for me on OS X El Capitan in terminal.

Comment: @Joseph, if `:version` shows you `-clipboard` then the build of Vim doesn't support the clipboard feature. I was talking about MacVim, which is a GUI app.

Comment: I use vim installed via brew within the terminal. Do you think it would be possible to compile vim with the clipboard feature?

Answer (score 139):

If the clipboard is enabled, you can copy a selected region to the clipboard by hitting `"*y`

To see if it is enabled, run `vim --version` and look for `+clipboard` or `-clipboard`.  For example, it's not enabled by default on my 10.5.6 box:

```
% which vim
/usr/bin/vim
% vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Nov 11 2008 17:20:43)
Included patches: 1-22
Compiled by _www@b77.apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
-clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
...
```

If it had been compiled with `+clipboard`, I'd be able to use the `"*` register to access the system clipboard.

I downloaded the [7.2 source](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/unix/vim-7.2.tar.bz2) and compiled it (easy as `tar xjf vim-7.2.tar.bz && cd vim72 && ./configure && make && sudo make install`), and the clipboard was enabled:

```
% which vim
/usr/local/bin/vim
% vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.2 (2008 Aug 9, compiled Mar 24 2009 17:31:52)
Compiled by rampion@Myrrhy.local
Normal version with GTK2 GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
...
+clientserver +clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
...
```

However, even after compiling, I couldn't copy to the clipboard when running vim in Terminal.app, only in X11.app.

Comment: I compiled the latest version with +clipboard and now the native clipboard works with it as the * register.  Also, setting "set clipboard=unnamed" in your .vimrc file makes the system clipboard the typical one.  I actually used  http://github.com/adamv/homebrew/blob/duplicates/Library/Formula/vim.rb  this homebrew formula to build and compile it.

Comment: Hmm, not sure why Vim didn't show up in my Homebrew, but I copied it down to /usr/local/Library/Formula, ran brew install vim, and it failed with "ld: library not found for -lruby-static". I'm using RVM and was on 1.8.7. When I switched to 1.9.2 the error was "ld: library not found for -lruby.1.9.1". The solution was to use system Ruby by first executing rvm use system.

Comment: A little easier than searching for the word "clipboard" in what is usually a long list of features: do `:echo has("clipboard")`.  If it shows 0, it's not compiled in.  If it shows 1, it is.

Comment: you can also get vim compiled with clipboard using homebrew:  `brew install vim`

Comment: Note that if you install vim through homebrew, it symlinks only `vim` not, `vi`, so `vi` still launches the OS X-included vim. Took me a while to figure out why clipboard still wasn't working.

Comment: Beware! I had a `+clipboard` version, but had installed `--with-client-server` which enables `+x11`, and trying to copy/paste to x11 in terminal vim on macOS didn't work :) I had to reinstall without `+clientserver`.

Answer (score 101):

You can visually select text and type `:w !pbcopy<CR>`

Or you can include the below key mappings in your `~/.vimrc` file. They cut/copy text in visual mode to the operating system's clipboard.

```
vmap <C-x> :!pbcopy<CR>  
vmap <C-c> :w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
```

source: http://drydevelopment.com/blog/vim-pbcopy-on-os-x

Comment: You can also select text from the command line like :1,10w !pbcopy to copy lines 1-10 to the clipboard. The w is important along with the space after it to keep original  text in place. The source link above is now broken but there is a discussion here: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing

Comment: I followed this to get this working in tmux: http://superuser.com/questions/231130/unable-to-use-pbcopy-while-in-tmux-session

Comment: @Wex Link has been fixed

Comment: Note this seems to only work for selecting whole lines. It doesn't seem to work if you only want to select part of a line. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16196826/how-to-filter-visual-selection

Comment: @Kevin Wheeler: you can try with following command which can solve non-linewise copy noremap <silent> <leader>y :<CR>:let @a=@" \| execute "normal! vgvy" \| let res=system("pbcopy", @") \| let @"=@a<CR>

Answer (score 45):

double-quote asterisk (<kbd>"</kbd><kbd>*</kbd>) before any yank command will yank the results into the copy buffer.  That works for Windows and Linux too.

Comment: just seems to emit a bell character and no other effect for me

Comment: In X11, Vim's "* is PRIMARY, "+ is CLIPBOARD, and SECONDARY doesn't get a named register.  (Not that anybody uses it...)

Comment: Perfectly. Really helps, especially with block selection (ctrl-v).

Comment: Since the question was specifically about Mac OS X, adding that it works for Mac "too" is unnecessary.

Comment: @PaulTomblin okay, fair enough :-)

Comment: Best response (imo). Worked for me :)

Answer (score 27):

On macos 10.8, vim is compiled with `-clipboard` so to use `"*y` you'll need to
recompile. Luckily `brew install vim` would compile a new version easily for you
and it will be `+clipboard`.

Comment: Something to keep in mind -  quite bizarrely, `brew install vim` with updates `vi`, and *not* `vim`. So you might have to alias things differently after installing vim with homebrew.

Answer (score 18):

Visually select the text and type:

```
ggVG
!tee >(pbcopy)
```

Which I find nicer than:

```
ggVG
:w !pbcopy
```

Since it doesn't flash up a prompt: "Press ENTER or type command to continue"

Comment: Still copies the whole line

Answer (score 12):

In my case I just had to do :

```
:set mouse=v
```

[please visit the original solution on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/436890/cant-copy-to-clipboard-from-vim)

Answer (score 11):

If you are using MacPorts you can upgrade your VIM to include clipboard support via:

```
port install vim +x +x11
```

Now you use the `"+` register to yank your text directly to your Mac clipboard.  Works like a charm.

Comment: This is just what I needed. One just needs to make sure that $PATH is correct and you're getting /opt/local/bin/vim not the Apple vim.

Answer (score 9):

If you are on MacOS X:

```
$ brew install vim
$ vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 [...]
```

Then, add to your .vimrc:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

Now you just need to be in *vim* and do `:%y`, to have all the content copied to your clipboard.

Comment: content is yanked but I can not paste outside of VIM.

Answer (score 5):

If your Vim is not compiled with clipboards, you wish to copy selected text instead of entire lines, you do not want to install MacVim or other GUI, the simplest solution is to add this line to your .vimrc:

```
map <C-c> y:e ~/clipsongzboard<CR>P:w !pbcopy<CR><CR>:bdelete!<CR>
```

To use it, simply visually select the text you want to copy, and then <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>. If you want a full explanation of this line read "[How to Copy to clipboard on vim](http://vimtips.quora.com/How-to-Copy-to-clipboard-on-vim)".

Comment: but its also giving me 2 black lines after the text copied

Answer (score 5):

Use [Homebrew's](http://brew.sh/) vim: `brew install vim`

Mac (as of 10.10.3 Yosemite) comes pre-installed with a system vim that does **not** have the `clipboard` flag enabled.

You can either compile vim for yourself and enable that flag, or simply use Homebrew's vim which is setup properly.

To see this for yourself, check out the stock system vim with `/usr/bin/vim --version`

You'll see something like:

```
$ /usr/bin/vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Nov  5 2014 21:00:28)
Compiled by root@apple.com
Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
... -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl ...
```

Note the `-clipboard`

With homebrew's vim you instead get

```
$ /usr/local/bin/vim --version

VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled May 10 2015 14:04:42)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-712
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
... +clipboard ...
```

Note the `+clipboard`

Comment: Then how to make the copy?

Comment: with brew's version of vim I was able to do what I wanted: I highlighted the lines using `V` then `:w !pbcopy` and it worked

Answer (score 4):

I used:

```
map <C-x> :!pbcopy<CR>
vmap <C-c> :w !pbcopy<CR><CR>
```

It worked really well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) when you're on a Mac to easily access the clipboard using the standard OS keys.

It's also fully backward compatible with normal Vim, so I don't even have to have a separate `.vimrc`.

Comment: I use MacVim and then symlinked the command-line vim synonyms into my `~/bin` to override the defaults.

Answer (score 2):

command-C? This at least works for the vim launched from within Terminal.app for text selected with mouse.

Comment: good naive answer but breaks output if you're using vertically-split subwindows in vim (which is actually the case I have in mind), or if the result is longer than one terminal screen

Comment: You are right, I didn't think of these cases. I leave my answer just to prevent others to give similar not helpful answers.

Answer (score 2):

[Fakeclip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098) implements the `+` and `*` buffers if they aren't natively supported.

Answer (score 2):

My main problem was the default OSX version of Vim. Installing it via homebrew added `+clipboard` to the build.

You can check with:

```
vim --version
```

to see if it says `-clipboard` or `+clipboard`.

Answer (score 2):

if you have the `+clipboard` option on your Vim installation (you can check with `:version`) and you are in visual mode you can do `"+y` This will yank the selection to the buffer `+` that is the clipboard.

I have added the following maps to my vimrc and it works fine.

`vmap <leader>y "+y`
: With this I can do `leader key` follow by `y` to copy to the clipboard in visual mode.

`nmap <leader>p "+p`
: With this I can do `leader key` follow by `p` to paste from the clipboard on normal mode.

PD : On Ubuntu I had to install vim-gtk to get the `+clipboard` option.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me in my `.vimrc`

```
set clipboard=unnamed
if has("unnamedplus") " X11 support
    set clipboard+=unnamedplus
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I am currently on OS X 10.9 and my efforts to compile vim with **+xterm_clipboard** brought me nothing. So my current solution is to use [MacVim in terminal mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5679658/1619451) with option `set clipboard=unnamed` in my ~/.vimrc file. Works perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Mac - Holding `option` key followed by `ctrl V` while selecting the text did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Shift cmd c – set copy mode 
Drag mouse,  select text, cmd c to copy selected text 
Cmd v to paste

Answer (score 0):

Best way to to use mapping.

For example:

```
nnoremap C "+y
vnoremap C "+y
nnoremap cC ^"+y$
```

This will map capital C to yank into the clipboard, without changing anything. Works with any vim.

Answer (score -1):

For Ubuntu users, the package you want to retrieve for using the clipboard is vim-full. The other packages (vim-tiny, vim) do not include the clipboard feature.

Comment: vim-full is no longer an ubuntu package name.  the default vim package (7.3.154) has a minimal set of features, including -clipboard.  Installing vim-gtk or vim-nox will provide a +clipboard version.

Answer (score -1):

Copying to clipboard using register '+' or '*'  is not working?

Reason: Your particular version of vim was compiled without clipboard support.Type vim --verion on console and you will see **-xterm_clipboard**. Installing vim with gui packages solves this issue. On ubuntu you can do this by typing on shell:

sudo apt-get install vim-gui-common

Now again do vim --version on console. Most probably, you would be seeing **+xterm_clipboard** now!!

So, now you can copy anything to clipboard using register + (like "+yy to copy current line to clipboard)

Answer (score -1):

on mac when anything else seems to work - select with mouse, right click choose copy. uff

Answer (score -1):

I meet the same issue, after install `macvim` still not working, finally I found a way to solve:

Try to uninstall all vim first,

`brew uninstall macvim`

`brew uninstall --force vim`

and reinstall macvim

`brew install macvim --with-override-system-vim`

Then you can use `"*y` or `"+y`, don't have to `set clipboard=unnamed`

Answer (score -2):

Command-c works for me in both MacVim and in the terminal.

Comment: Traditional copy and paste does not work with Vim buffers and can completely mess up your formatting. For example, copying 15 lines of nested objects with Cmd + C and then pasting with Cmd + V will cause it to lose an understanding of the nesting. This very likely depends on your settings in your .vimrc and can be very particular