# How to share clipboard between tmux/vim and osx

Tags: macos, terminal, clipboard, tmux

I found solution for iterm+vim here -> [Vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard)

Now i use fakeclip, and it work in vim directly, but not when i use tmux to split terminal window.

Comment: Access to the pasteboard in Mac OS X works differently from most systems. You may need to [patch tmux](http://superuser.com/questions/245893/copy-paste-not-working-in-macvim-when-launched-in-tmux) to have it make some special system calls that let its children retain access to the pasteboard.

Comment: You can try to use `xclip`, I use it on Ubuntu GNU/Linux to work with clipboard. GNU/Linux and OSX both use XWindow so maybe it will too.

Answer (score 5):

Latest beta of iTerm2 has built-in tmux integration, which would take care of this.

Answer (score 4):

[fakeclip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098) has been updated to work with both tmux and with screen:

- v0.2.5 : added tmux support. (2009-11-11)
- v0.2.10 : added a [fix for tmux](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip/pull/5) when screen is also installed. (2012-01-21)