# Compile Vim 7.3 with +clientserver feature on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, vim, compilation, client-server

How do I compile Vim with the `clientserver` feature on Mac OS X? I have the [vim-7.3.tar.bz2 source](http://www.vim.org/sources.php)

I understand that MacVim has this built in, **but it only works when the GUI is running**.  I want to work with a CLI version, as my work is so much easier with the CLI (I can switch to the Terminal with ease, for example).

I compiled Vim 7.3 with the following `./configure` options

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge
```

I have looked at this [question on Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2807/1243), but it only takes care of the Ubuntu solution. Also, since I enabled the `huge` feature set, I should expect `+clientserver`, according to the [vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#+feature-list):

> Thus if a feature is marked with "N", it is included in the normal, big and huge versions of Vim.

### Update:

The server feature only works with GUI MacVim. To reproduce this:

```
$ Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim --servername VIM
```

The in another console:

```
$ vim --serverlist # does not output anything
```

Whereas if I'll fire up the GUI MacVim,

```
$ vim --serverlist
VIM1
```

But my requirement is to work in CLI Vim.

Comment: Does `vim --version` actually include `+clientserver`? Also what is the output of `which vim`?

Comment: @AndrewMarshall, my `vim` is aliased to the path where my compiled Vim is located. `--version` only has `-clientserver`

Comment: Since I am using YCM, I'd like to keep using CLI macvim --- Is there a way to allow server running even in terminal? Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got it to work by adding `--enable-gui=gtk2`

```
./configure --enable-rubyinterp --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge --enable-gui=gtk2
```

Then run from the console:

```
$ vim --servername FOOBAR_SERVER
```

From another console:

```
$ vim --serverlist
FOOBAR_SERVER
```

Or from within any Vim instance:

```
:echo serverlist()
FOOBAR_SERVER
```

Note that X11.app will also boot up as it is necessary for the Vim server to function.

Comment: What was the full path to configure?  I see you just have it listed as ./configure.  I'm running into this exact same issue.

Comment: @bigtunacan, sorry for the very late response.  Whenever you want to compile from a source tarball, the `configure` script is usually in the parent of `src`. In other words, it is in the same level as `src`.

Answer (score 11):

You can now do this using [HomeBrew](http://brew.sh/) as well:

```
brew install vim --with-client-server
```

It looks like [this was added back in 2013](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/23355), so I'm not sure why it's not mentioned more frequently.

Just in case you were doing this to start using [Pterosaur](https://github.com/ardagnir/pterosaur) like me, after installing vim with HomeBrew, you might have to force the symlink if you're using MacVim through HomeBrew as well.

```
brew link --overwrite macvim
```

Then, just set the `extensions.pterosaur.vimbinary` to `/usr/local/bin/vim` in the Firefox `about:config` page and it should work. I'm typing this using Pterosaur right now, though occasionally Python crashes.

Comment: `brew install macvim --with-client-server` worked for me, not the vim one. Hope it helps

Comment: Can be looked up at https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/80fdd1a8407b89b90602a0215f3712c9e6ca3aea/Formula/vim.rb#L21

There are all possible options in combination with homebrew.

Comment: It's working well with `vim` without having to using `macvim`. The thing is you have to launch XQuartz once after installation. And you have to restart or logout/login your mac.

Comment: it said invalid option :(

Comment: Error: invalid option: --with-client-server

Answer (score 9):

Using MacPorts:

```
$ sudo port install vim +huge +gtk2
```

In a new window:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/vim --servername FOO
```

And in another window:

```
$ /opt/local/bin/vim --serverlist
FOO
```

Quick. Easy.

***EDIT***

The `+gtk2` is required to make it work, `+huge` is not enough. Actually, I think that it should work without `+gtk2` as long as you have `+x11`. Unfortunatelly I'm not on my Mac anymore so I can't try. The whole thing takes about 3 minutes so you could try it.

***ENDEDIT***

Comment: +huge +x11 did it for me.  I didn't need gtk2.

Answer (score 3):

You could just run the CLI version of `vim` included in MacVim.  With MacVim installed as `/Applications/MacVim.app`, the CLI version is:

```
/Applications/MacVim.app/Contents/MacOS/Vim
```

This is compiled with the `clientserver` feature.  You can add a symlink to this to put it in your `$PATH`.

Comment: I did mention in the question details that the server only works with the GUI. It's also mentioned in the MacVim caveats that you'll find in `:help remote`

Answer (score 2):

Even after reading all these answers, I had to spend several hours for making things work, so I would like to give some clear steps for someone like me.

Given that almost all of the Mac users are using Homebrew, my solution is using Homebrew for installtion.

1. `brew cask install xquartz`
2. Launch XQuartz. You might need to update it.
3. Logout and login, or restart your Mac.
4. `brew install vim --with-client-server`

Now if you launch vim, XQuartz will be launched as well. And if you run vim with `--servername <name>` argument, you will be able to see the server using `--serverlist` option.

But after this, you have to launch XQuartz with vim and also you have to do some work for making clipboard thing work again. I found [a blog post](http://www.markcampbell.me/2016/04/12/setting-up-yank-to-clipboard-on-a-mac-with-vim.html) and followed it but failed to make it work correctly regarding the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

You should get a command line executable with MacVim.

- [How to run mvim (MacVim) from Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056137/how-to-run-mvim-macvim-from-terminal).

Comment: Simply linking to another question is an indication that you should be voting to close as a duplicate, not posting an answer. That question also doesn't answer this one anyway.

Comment: My point is that if you want a CLI version, then you get one with a precompiled MacVim. Does that not do what you require?

Comment: How does that question answer that at all? `mvim` is not CLI Vim, it's a script to open GVim. Very different.