# What is the name of the CLI Vim process as seen by Mac OS X?

Tags: vim, applescript

I'm trying to get this script to run, from the [Skim wiki](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/skim-app/index.php?title=TeX_and_PDF_Synchronization#Editor_Script_for_VIM)

```
#!/bin/bash

file="$1"
line="$2"

[ "${file:0:1}" == "/" ] || file="${PWD}/$file"

exec osascript \
  -e "set ESC to ASCII character 27" \
  -e "tell application \"Vim\" to activate" \
  -e "tell application \"System Events\"" \
  -e "  tell process \"Vim\"" \
  -e "    keystroke ESC & \":set hidden\" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":if bufexists('$file')\" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":exe \\\":buffer \\\" . bufnr('$file')\"  & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":else \" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":    edit ${file// /\\\\ }\" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":endif\" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \":$line\" & return " \
  -e "    keystroke \"zO\" " \
  -e "  end tell" \
  -e "end tell"
```

If I try to run it from the command line:

```
# Go to line 20 of some_file
$ ./that_script "some_file" 20
```

I get the following error:

```
56:64: execution error: File Vim wasn’t found. (-43)
```

### Attempts

I've tried all sorts:

```
tell application \"vim\" to activate <-- File vim wasn't found
tell application \"/usr/bin/vim\" to activate <-- this raises a 10810 error
tell application \"/path/to/my/own/compiled/vim\" <-- this raises a 10810 error
```

### Objective

I'm trying to "talk" to a Vim instance running from a Terminal, not a GUI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that you have `+clientserver` (from [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10231223/compile-vim-7-3-with-clientserver-feature-on-mac-os-x)) working, I assume you don't need an answer here anymore but here it is anyway:

AppleScript generally doesn't deal with command line programs.

You can use AppleScript to talk to MacVim (`tell application "MacVim" to activate`) but you can't reach CLI Vim at all. AppleScript is for GUI apps only.

Now, most (I hesitate to write "all") Mac OS X GUI applications expose at least a minimal interface for AppleScript called "dictionnary": you can activate the app, get the number of windows, print the active document, open a file… and simulate keystrokes.

The script in your example works — more or less — but only with a GUI Vim. There is a small number of such apps for Mac OS X and this script is designed to work with one called Vim.app. You can change `Vim` to `MacVim` if you want but you won't be able to make it work with CLI Vim.

Comment: Thank you! I just looked up the Dictionary a few hours ago and realized that apps will have to "meet halfway" and provide an Applescript interface.

Comment: Hi @Kit, have you figured out a solution to have skim back-search working with CLI vim/macvim yet?  I am having the same problem and appreciate if you can share your solution if it's solved