# Why isn't this file being copied to my $PATH?

Tags: bash, macvim

I was trying to add the mvim shell script to /usr/local/bin form bash as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056137/how-to-run-mvim-macvim-from-terminal) and everything seemed to work; however, I am still getting "command not found" whenever I try to execute the script.

From the directory where my mvim file is (Downloads), I typed:

```
sudo cp -v mvim /usr/local/bin
```

and I get output:

```
mvim -> /usr/local/bin
```

and then it doesn't work whether I type `mvim` or `mvim -v`

I've never added something to my $PATH before, but even after looking up a number of tutorials on how it is done, I can't seem to get `mvim` to work as a terminal command.

**EDIT:**

```
echo $PATH

/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

and

```
ls -l mvim

-rwxr-xr-x ...
```

and

```
ls -l /usr/local/bin

-rwxr-xr-x ...
```

Comment: Are you inside the `/usr/local/bin` folder when you do your `ls`?

Comment: I can't seem to navigate there, it just says "Not a directory". And if I just type "/usr/local/bin" into terminal, vim opens (not mvim). Have I mapped "/usr/local/bin" to vim command or something?

Comment: Very interesting. I will update my answer.

Comment: Can you show the output of `ls -l /usr/local/bin` please?

Comment: `ls -l /usr/local/bin`


`-rwxr-xr-x  1 root ...`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13276/discussion-between-rodrigue-and-stariz77)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Does */usr/local/bin* exists?

If you run `sudo cp -v mvim /usr/local/bin` and the `/usr/local/bin` folder does not exist, cp will copy `mvim` to the `/usr/local/` folder and name it `bin`.

You need to first create the folder with `sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/bin`. Then, you can copy `mvim` with the previous `cp` command.

#### Is *mvim* executable?

Have you made sure that `/usr/local/bin/mvim` has the *executable* flag set? Try `ls -l /usr/local/bin/mvim` and if the result starts with `-rw-r--r--`, then *mvim* is not executable.

You then need to run `sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mvim`. If you now run the previous `ls` command again, the result should start with `-rwxr-xr-x`. The `x` means that the file is now *executable* by its owner, members of its group, and all other users too.

#### Is */usr/local/bin* in your *PATH*?

Have you made sure that `/usr/local/bin` is part of your `PATH` variable?

Try `echo $PATH` and if the output does not contain `/usr/local/bin`, then the shell will not look for commands there. You then need to run `export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Excellent advice :)  However, I'd still like to see an "ls -l" of the original "mvim" file, and an "echo" of the current $PATH.  Just to be sure :)

Comment: I am getting: "Not a directory" when typing in the command. I made an edit to my question showing output for `echo $PATH`.

Comment: @paulsm4 thank you. I have updated my answer to cover the potential `PATH` issue

Comment: @stariz77 Have you tried the suggested `ls` command? Can you post the output please?

Answer (score 1):

Check:

1. If /usr/local/bin/mvim is executable (add exec bit if not: chmod +x /usr/local/bin/mvim)
2. If /usr/local/bin is in $PATH (`echo $PATH`)

Answer (score 1):

Either start a new shell, or type:

```
hash -r
```

so that the shell re-inspects the directories in the `$PATH`. (It caches the contents for efficiency, you need to reload that cache when you add things to directories in your path.)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you posted:

```
mvim -> /usr/local/bin
```

I believe that's *wrong*.  It *looks* like "mvim" is a *symbolic link* that points to the *directory* /usr/local/bin.

If so, this is *not* what you want!

Please do the following:

1. Open a terminal (command-line) window.
2. "cd" to the directory with your original "mvim" (the one you tried to copy to /usr/localbin)
3. Cut/paste:

   a) the directory name

   b) `ls -l mvim`

   c) `echo $PATH`

The "echo $PATH" is also important.

Please cut/paste all three into your response.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: That is normal output of `cp -v`

Comment: @Igor Chubin - if stariz77 cuts/pastes the output I requested, we should be able to resolve his problem.  Without it, we're just "guessing".  I don't like guessing - do you? ;)