# How to make terminal recognize command "gvim" or "mvim"?

Tags: vim, text-editor, macvim

I am not sure I understand correctly from the readme file how to install vim onto my mac. After installation, I still cannot seem to open files while typing `gvim HelloWorld.c` into terminal. How can I permanently fix the `gvim` command for terminal to recognize all the time?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056137/how-to-run-mvim-macvim-from-terminal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mac OS X already ships with a slightly underpowered but perfectly working vim build so you only have to issue that command in your terminal:

```
$ vim filename
```

MacVim is a more featureful version that comes with a GUI *and* a CLI executable. Is that what you installed?

The archive you downloaded contains MacVim.app and a shell script called `mvim`.

If you don't plan to use Vim in or from your terminal, you don't need that `mvim` script at all.

If you do, the simplest solution is to put that script somewhere in your `$PATH`. To do so, check the value of `$PATH` with the following command:

```
$ echo $PATH
```

and copy the script into one of the listed directories:

```
$ cp /path/to/mvim /some/directory/mvim
```

After that's done, you can call the MacVim GUI from your terminal with:

```
$ mvim filename
```

or the MacVim CLI with:

```
$ mvim -v filename
```