# zsh: command not found: mvim

Tags: vim, macvim, iterm2

Recently I've installed [MacVim](http://macvim-dev.github.io/macvim/) and I'm having an issue with run it using iTerm. When I try to run it using the `mvim` from the iTerm it appeared `command not found: mvim`. I've tried the solution that provided on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056137/how-to-run-mvim-macvim-from-terminal) but it didn't help. Can anyone please help about this?

Comment: Where did you put the `mvim` script you downloaded with MacVim.app?

Comment: I downloaded the MacVim from here: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases/tag/snapshot-95 and there's no mvim script when I downloaded the MacVim.dmg

Comment: [Hmm… yes there is](http://i.imgur.com/qeV0Ng9.png).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Echo the value of your `$PATH` variable while at your prompt; the `mvim` file has to be in one of the directories listed there in order to be found when you try to run it.

Either move the `mvim` script there, or add the directory it is currently located in to your PATH via your `.zshrc`.

Comment: I didn't notice the `mvim` script is available on the `MacVim.dmg` package. Everything is good now.

Answer (score 1):

I've got this way:
`brew install macvim --override-system-vim --custom-icons --with-cscope --with-lua --enable-pythoninterp --enable-python3interp --ovrride-system-vi --with-python --with-python3`

Answer (score 1):

I solved it by this, you may try it:

```
brew unlink vim
brew link macvim
```