# Mac OS restrictions while attempting to use Vim Valloric/YouCompleteMe Plugin

Tags: vim, vi, macvim

If I attempt to use the Valloric/YouCompleteMe Vim plugin on Mac OS Catalina, am I absolutely required to install MacVim due to the Python 3.6+ requirements?

My issue is that MacVim opens in a separate program and would complicate a basic workflow instead of just using the system Vim.

"In mid 2020, YCM dropped support for Python 3.5 runtime.

Why?

On 13th September 2020, Python 3.5 will be officially end of life. And therefore, so will its relationship with YouCompleteMe and ycmd."

Source:
https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's required, it's possible it will work, but there wont be support for new issues. I would recommend trying to meet the requirements.

To address the second issue, macvim can be incorporated into your workflow to work exactly the same as your system vim. Here's a question that can help with that,

[How to run mvim (MacVim) from Terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056137/how-to-run-mvim-macvim-from-terminal)