# Copy into the system clipboard from local vim on mac

Tags: macos, vim, ssh, terminal, clipboard

It seems like versions of this question have been asked here before, but I haven't been able to glean from them the exact response to what I am looking for.

Say I open up a `.txt` file via `vim` on my mac machine and I then want to copy a line from that file to be used in another `.txt` file or in a `google search` or in `terminal` during an `ssh` session. What would be the ***simplest*** way to do this?

Thanks,

---

EDIT

Found a potential duplicate: [Vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard). But I am open to improvements! :)

Comment: `"+Y` would be the simples, look at `se clipboard=unnamed` too

Comment: possible duplicate of [vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard)

Answer (score 3):

i'm not sure wether it works for osx too but here on linux i use `"+<yank>`, there is also `"*<yank>`

see also http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Copy_an_Entire_Buffer_to_the_Clipboard

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the other answer, use the + register or * register.
In some environments, * and + may not behave as expected.  To enable the expected behavior, use a plugin like [fakeclip](https://github.com/kana/vim-fakeclip). Fakeclip enables clipboard support when it is not available out of the box.