# Fix Vim + Tmux yank/paste on unnamed register

Tags: vim, tmux

While using vim inside a tmux session I cannot yank or paste to the unnamed register. Going to a named register works fine, but unnamed never works.

Error is:

```
E353: Nothing in register *
```

Without tmux, vim works fine using my current settings. How do I fix it so I can use <kbd>y</kbd> then <kbd>p</kbd> without errors and without specifying the register?

Comment: Could you show your tmux.conf?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

From the error message (`Nothing in register *`), it appears that when you do a plain<sup>?</sup> `p`, your instance of Vim is using the [`*` register](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/gui.txt.html#quotestar) instead of the [unnamed register](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#quotequote)<sup>*</sup>. This is probably because your [`clipboard` option](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27clipboard%27) includes the value `unnamed`. When configured this way, Vim will use the `*` register instead of the unnamed register for yank, delete, change, and put operations by default (i.e. unless you specify another register with a `"` prefix; e.g. `"ap` to put from the `a` register).

<sup>*The unnamed register is actually named `"` (double quote). It is only “unnamed” in the sense that you do not have to name it to use it (it is the default). I.e. you do not have to say `""p` to put from the unnamed register, just `p`.</sup>

The default value of `clipboard` does not contain `unnamed`, so it is probably coming from some bit of your configuration (or a plugin). The command `:verbose set clipboard?` will show you the script that set the current value. If this is being done in your configuration file, then you might want to not do it when you are running under *tmux*. E.g:

```
if $TMUX == ''
    set clipboard+=unnamed
endif
```

Alternatively, there may be some way to let instances of Vim-inside-*tmux* access the GUI selection/clipboard (thus work with the `*` register and/or `unnamed` in `clipboard`). If you are running Mac OS X, you may want to look at [my workaround wrapper](https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard) that re-enables clipboard access for processes running inside a *tmux* session. If you are using some other OS or GUI, then you will need to find out how Vim would normally talk to the GUI and why it is not working (e.g. wrong DISPLAY value under X11, possibly due to attaching to an old session that is running a shell that has an out-of-date value).

Comment: You are correct, my .vimrc had the set clipboard=unnamed line. I added the conditional and now it works correctly in and out of tmux.

Comment: All the other answers just randomly try different settings without mind, ONLY you point out why! Thanks.

Comment: Should I install it with the `--with-wrap-pbcopy-and-pbpaste` option in brew?

Answer (score 49):

Here is what works for me in vim/tmux/osx:

1. Install [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/)
2. Install reattach-to-user-namespace:
   `brew install reattach-to-user-namespace`
3. in .vimrc: `set clipboard=unnamed`
4. Tell tmux to use the system clipboard:
   In .tmux.conf: `set-option -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l bash"`

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/j9wnfw

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Comment: for `zsh` users of course replace `bash` with `zsh`.

Comment: Remember to restart any login sessions (i.e. restart your iTerm/Terminal windows) after doing this.

Comment: The third step can be omitted if using `"+p` to paste from system clipboard, if you want to separate default vim register from system clipboard (the rest was still necessary for me to get it working in tmux).

Answer (score 4):

The [fakeclip](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2098) plugin makes the clipboard register behave as expected in many terminals and has support for tmux/screen.  Are you using it? It may resolve your issue.

As well, you may be interested in this tip... It's not applicable to your question, but related.  Depending on what type of system/terminal you're running tmux in, you may need some tweaks in your `.tmux.conf`.  For example here's an excerpt of my `.tmux.conf` on OS X (with some instructions in comments):

```
# To use pbcopy and pbpaste on OS X, get this wrapper and install
#    git clone https://github.com/ChrisJohnsen/tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard.git
#    cd tmux-MacOSX-pasteboard/
#    make reattach-to-user-namespace
#    mv reattach-to-user-namespace /usr/local/bin
# After installing, the default command can be reset to use the 'reattach-to-user-namespace' 
# wrapper that was compiled/installed as descripted above.
set -g default-command "reattach-to-user-namespace -l /bin/bash"
# #Next, create Ctrl-c and Ctrl-v mappings
bind C-c run "tmux save-buffer - | reattach-to-user-namespace pbcopy"
bind C-v run "tmux set-buffer $(reattach-to-user-namespace pbpaste); tmux paste-buffer"
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but it also might be that your `.tmux.conf` contains the following line:

`set -g set-clipboard off`

combined with a `.vimrc` containing

`set clipboard=unnamed`

this will lead to vim trying to use a clipboard that is not there.

Answer (score 0):

To add a couple notes from my experience on OSX to the accepted answer:

- Make sure you do `set clipboard=unnamed` and not `set clipboard=unnamedplus`
- I had to kill my tmux server (`$ killall tmux` or `$ tmux kill-session -a`). Reloading the tmux configuration files showed that default-command was set but did not give vim access to the system clipboard.