# tmux - copy to system buffer via keyboard selection

Tags: console, tmux

Is it possible like in Vim to copy keyboard selected text to system buffer.
On Mac Os and Linux I'm using `+` (`"`+`+`) buffer, that works as system buffer, so how to do the same in tmux?

Comment: On osx, I suggest installing `reattach-to-user-namespace`. Here in SO, some other questions/answers covered that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18674997/1046584

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fix Vim + Tmux yank/paste on unnamed register](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11404800/fix-vim-tmux-yank-paste-on-unnamed-register)

Comment: @LuísBianchin, Vim works perfectly with copy paste. But when I go to navigation mode via <Ctrl+B>+<[> and the to visual selection <v> I cannot copy to system buffet.

Comment: are you using `reattach-to-user-namespace`?