# What is the Vim command to copy content from a file (opened in Vim editor) and paste in Firefox browser address bar?

Tags: vim, copy, yank

I'm trying to copy a text (link) from my file (opened in vim), go to FF browser and paste the copied text in address bar. How should I do that without touching Mouse?

I am using Ubuntu OS and vim editor

**Steps**:

- Open a file using vim 
   
  vim temp.txt
- copy a text line from temp.txt 
  say the file has text  www.google.com 
  I'm using command v(for visual mode), shift+$ (to select the line) and y (to yank)
- paste on Firefox browser address bar so that I can visit google.com

but not working (not able to paste).

Please help me with the command ?

Thank you

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416253/how-to-map-yank-to-oss-clipboard-in-vim)

Comment: Well, what are you trying? Copy to the shared clipboard ("+y) and then change to firefox, select address bar with Ctrl+L and paste with Ctrl+V.

Comment: @SBI why not put that in answer?

Comment: Vim is multi-platform; at least tell us the operating system you're using; the exact steps may depend on that.

Comment: @Kent I didn't know if the problem wasn't with something else. I've added my answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turning my comment into an answer:

`"+` is the register that refers to the system clip board, this works for Linux as well as Windows (this is what I was able to test). You can copy to it with the `"+y` key strokes, given that you've previously selected something. To copy the whole line you're on, you can use `"+yy` (used as an example, you might have to google other cordes). You can then switch to firefox, with `alt + tab` for example, and then select the address bar using `Ctrl+L`, and paste using your system's paste shortcut, most likely `Ctrl+V`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `"*` register to do this. For example, to yank a visual selection into the clipboard:

```
v2j " select two lines
"*y " yank into * register
```

You can use something similar with `d` to “cut” a selection or line; for example, to “cut” a line and have it available in the clipboard:

```
"*dd " delete current line and paste into clipboard
```

Answer (score 1):

To open URLs directly from Vim (with your default browser), there are plugins that provide convenient mappings for that. I can recommend the [open-browser.vim - Open URI with your favorite browser](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3133) plugin for that.

This is more efficient than copy-and-pasting from Vim into your browser (and it doesn't clobber the clipboard contents, neither).