# How to filter visual selection?

Tags: vim

Suppose we have some nice bunch of text:

```
Hello world
```

and we select the `world` in visual mode. Then we could filter the visual selection using a shiny command like this one:

```
:'<,'>!echo foobar
```

However, that would replace the entire line with `foobar` instead of just the `world`. Why is this, and how can we just replace the `world`?

Comment: see `:help visual_example`

Comment: @evilotto nice trick, didn't find it before..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `:!` filter command always works on *entire lines* (this is as old as the original *vi*, embedding *Ex commands* that start with `:`), and the `'<,'>` range also only specifies *lines*.

You can use the venerable [vis plugin](http://vim.sourceforge.net/scripts/script.php?script_id=1195) to achieve your result; it offers a `:B` command that limits the following command to the visually selected text.

```
:'<,'>B !echo foobar
```

The plugin works for all kind of Ex commands; for `:substitute` within the selection you can also use the special `\%V` atom, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I want to use it inside a plugin. Does that mean that every user should install the vis plugin by side, or is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Unless you can reduce your use to a simple subset that you can easily implement yourself in Vimscript, I would recommend to delegate this to the vis plugin. Why re-invent the wheel?!