# Vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard still fail to work

Tags: macos, vim

I refer to [Vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard) and its provided solution http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mac_OS_X_clipboard_sharing

But I still can't copy the content in Vim to Mac OS X clipboard.

I tried using Command + C, or `"+y`, `"*y`, all failed.

- My OS X version is El Capitan, Vi version is as following, 7.3. it seems that Mac default Vim didn't compile feature `clipboard`

  ```
  vi --version
  VIM - Vi IMproved 7.3 (2010 Aug 15, compiled Aug 22 2015 15:38:58)
  Compiled by root@apple.com
  Normal version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
  -arabic +autocmd -balloon_eval -browse +builtin_terms +byte_offset +cindent 
  -clientserver -clipboard +cmdline_compl +cmdline_hist +cmdline_info +comments
  ```
- I have set set it in `~/.vimrc`:

  ```
  set clipboard=unnamed
  ```
- I launch my Vi in terminal.app of Mac OS X, such as press Command+Space, and input terminal, press Enter.

Any comment?

Solution:
I use brew to resolve this problem. 
go to http://brew.sh and installed a vim which support clipboard.

Comment: You need a Vim build with clipboard support. Try MacVim.

Comment: To check if your Vim has clipboard support: `vim --version | grep -i clipboard`. You should see `+clipboard`. If you see `-clipboard` your Vim was compiled without clipboard support...

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a tool like [Clipper](https://github.com/wincent/clipper).

Comment: Same here. Neither `"+` nor `"*` works. Clipboard was enabled. I am using Vim 8.

Comment: Yes, same here, clipboard is enabled but still not working