# MacOs Terminal Vim Copy to System Clipboard

Tags: vim

I am using Homebrew Vim from MacOS Terminal. The problem I am having now is to copy in vim to System Clipboard. I follow the guide online, which told me to use "+y after selection texts in visual mode. However, when I hit the corresponding keys on "+y, the system responds with a sound indicating that such key combination is illegal. What am I doing wrong?

I did what is suggested. Here is what my dot file looks like:

```
 set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime


 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
 source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim

 try
 source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
 catch
 endtry


 " Define Key Mapping
 inoremap jj <Esc>

 set clipboard=unnamedplus

 " Run Python file with one command
 nnoremap <buffer> <C-M> :exec '!python' shellescape(@%, 1)<cr>

 "YouCompleteMe virtual env config
 let g:ycm_global_ycm_extra_conf = '~/.vim/.ycm_extra_conf.py'
```

Further, the `:reg` does not show the `"+` or `"*` registry.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vim: copy selection to OS X clipboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/677986/vim-copy-selection-to-os-x-clipboard)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmacos%5D+%5Bvim%5D+copy+to+system+clipboard

Comment: I read the thread and copying into system registry works for macvim but it  doesn't work in my terminal vim.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with add the line:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

to your .vimrc [^1](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Accessing_the_system_clipboard). For using + you might want to try with `set clipboard=unnamedplus`.

If you are not sure how to do this, just type in:

```
cd ~ && echo 'set clipboard=unnamedplus' >> .vimrc
```

See more information by `:h clipboard-unnamedplus`.

Notice that this this option works only in vim that is compiled with X11 & clipboard feature.

Regards

Comment: that doesn't work. I have tried it before. I have updated my vimrc file.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. It was my vim does not support clipboard feature.